# how to loop through php object and replace a string in each property ( variable )

Tags: php

I need to remove these ' & ' characters from each property of a php object

I tried the code below but it's not working...what am I missing?

thanks dudes

```
foreach($query_item as $key => $value)
{
    $key = str_replace(' & ',' &amp; ',$value);
}
```

Comment: If this foreach is outside of $query_item (which I presume so as your not using $this) are the properties public or otherwise accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer to $value by reference, and modify it in place:

```
foreach($query_item as $key => &$value)
{
    $value = str_replace(' & ',' &amp; ',$value);
}
```

The alternative would be to reference the item within the object using $key:

```
foreach($query_item as $key => $value)
{
    $query_item->$key = str_replace(' & ',' &amp; ',$value);
}
```

I'll also point out [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/htmlentities), while we're on the subject of replacing & with &amp;.

Comment: Just for my curiosity, the only difference in your first suggestion and mjr's original is that mjr was modifying $key whilst you are modifying $value. Is that the mistake?

Comment: Modifying by Reference is smart. But the second example isn't $query_item an array? $query_item[$key] = ... ?

Comment: No. He said: "I need to remove the '&' character from each property of a php object."
An object is not an array, therefore you'd need to use ->$key. However, the first one would work best. Just remove the spaces, they're unnecessary and might mess up if someone uses something like `this&that`.

Comment: $query_item is an object

your second method worked for me, thanks!

Comment: I should have been more clear, I actually do want to spaces around the ampersand, but thanks for lookin out for me

Comment: @JYelton, I substituted &$value for $value in the foreach(). (That's the important "by reference" bit.)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($query_item as $key => &$value)
{
    $query_item[$key] = str_replace(' & ',' &amp; ',$value);
}
```